# Proper way to represent anti-matter in a 3D model?

Tags: quantum-state

I'm trying to create a simple 3D model to represent the basic atomic structures involved in matter (i.e., Matter, Molecules, Atoms, Electrons, Protons, Neutrons, Quarks, Anti-Matter,
Forces, etc.). I want it to be as technical accurate as you can get in a 3D child's toy...which means not that technically accurate.

I think I have all the particles figured out except for anti-matter.

How would I physically represent that...as simply another corresponding set of three anti-quarks, anti-elections, forces that basically mimics the regular atom? Would they always be near each other? Etc.?